# ASP.NET Sitemap Provider sitemap tabs not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS2005 and I'm having some trouble with the sitemap tabs.

I have assigned 2 roles in my ASP.NET Configuration tool, and assigned each user with a role.

My login is working normally, and the **access control is working**. If I am not logged in and I try to access a role restricted page, it will redirect me to login page.

However, when I logged in, some of the site nodes which are suppose to display when I am logged in with the correct privileged user, it still does not show.

---

Before login:
[image]

---

After login: [image]

From the screenshots above, my nodes only showed `Home` in both logged in and not logged in. I should see a Database Management tab which is unrestricted to `admin01`.

---

Below is my `Web.config` code snippet:

```
    <system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
  <roleManager enabled="true" />
  <pages styleSheetTheme="DataWebControls" />

        <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider"
                  description="Default SiteMap provider."
                  type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
                  siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
                  securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
        <compilation debug="true"/> 
    </system.web>
```

---

If I remove the whole code from `<siteMap></siteMap>`, my nodes will appear as normal:

[image]

---

I am not expecting a perfect solution as I do not know if the information I provided is sufficient, but I will appreciate any help given.

If more info is needed from me, please tell me and I will provide additional information.

Thank you

---

EDITED: Added `Web.sitemap` code snippet:

```
<siteMapNode url="/Project/Default.aspx"
          title="Home" description="Home">

    <siteMapNode title="Database Management"
     description="Database tab">

        <siteMapNode url="/Project/Database/Employee.aspx"
         title="Employee"
         description="" />

        <siteMapNode url="/Project/Databaase/Customer.aspx"
          title="Customer"
          description="" />

        <siteMapNode url="/Project/Database/Goods.aspx"
          title="Goods"
          description="" />

        <siteMapNode url="/Project/Database/Transactions.aspx"
          title="Past Transactions"
          description="" />

    </siteMapNode>

</siteMapNode>
```

---

EDITED: Added `Access role screenshot` on folder `/Project/Database`:

[image]
[image]

---

Additional info:

*Even if access rules are not created, and users are not assigned with any roles, the `Database` nodes are still not displayed*

Comment: It seems that our web.sitemap file is not configured correctly. could you please edit your post and add your web.sitemap and add some information what roles you defined in your project - thx

Comment: my sitemap can be displayed if sitemab tabs are not included in web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution for you.

The web configs that are restricting access...

First allow access and then deny it :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin1" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration
```

When ı do it vice versa the link disaappears and in the above way it appears..

Hope it solves your problem.... Since I created a solution for this and tested. (Since I am using sqlsitemapprovider)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding roles attribute to the relevant sitemapnodes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap>
<siteMapNode url="/Project/Default.aspx" 
          title="Home" description="Home"> 

    <siteMapNode title="Database Management" 
     description="Database tab" roles="Admin"> 

        <siteMapNode url="/Project/Database/Employee.aspx" 
         title="Employee" roles="Employee,Admin" 
         description="" /> 

        <siteMapNode url="/Project/Databaase/Customer.aspx" 
          title="Customer" roles="Customer,Employee,Admin" 
          description="" /> 

        <siteMapNode url="/Project/Database/Goods.aspx" 
          title="Goods" 
          description="" /> 

        <siteMapNode url="/Project/Database/Transactions.aspx" 
          title="Past Transactions" 
          description="" /> 

    </siteMapNode> 
</siteMapNode> 
</siteMap>
```

Have you checked the web.config files that the web site management tools added in to the folders that you restricted access to? Since sometimes the problem lies there..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin,Employee" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have checked the `web.config` files in each folder, and the authorization are correct. I have also tried to add in the the roles in my siteMapNods, but it still doesn't work.